# Mask the Phone no using Regex in c#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

We have a Phone no field, which can be of maximum 9 digit and we need to mask the Phone no (which is basically a string) to show on UI as a mask value.

We have tried below code snippet :

```
var pattern="^(/d{2})(/d{3})(/d*)$";
var regExp=new Regex(pattern);
return regExp.Replace(value, "$1-$2-$3");
```

this snippet works for 123456789 and displays (123) 456-789, but for 12345 it displays ()  12-345.

Could you please suggest what will be the best suitable option here to display phone no as (123) 456-789 for 123456789 and (123) 45 for 12345 Phone no.

Comment: Well `12345` isn't a valid phone number.  Why don't you validate it before attempting to format it as a phone number?  It doesn't make sense to format it as a phone number if it isn't a valid number.

Comment: what should it display for 12345?

Comment: Phone no would be free text as of now in system.

Comment: I think `/d` should be `\d`.

Comment: Why are you limiting phone numbers to 9 digits? Oxford's phone number is +44 1865 270000.

Comment: ok. Lets consider a free text no. For that I am looking for the suggestions

Comment: @mayankgupta How is that any different from what you have already asked?  Your question already deals with a "free text no"

Comment: @Amy, I want to display the Phone no as pre-defined masked text like (123) 456-789.

Comment: Yes, we got that already.  It's in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
           string[] inputs = { "123456789", "12345" };

           string pattern = @"^(?'one'\d{3})(?'two'\d{3})(?'three'\d{3})|(?'one'\d{3})(?'two'\d{2})";
           string output = "";
           foreach (string input in inputs)
           {
               Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
               if (match.Groups["three"].Value  == "")
                   output = string.Format("({0}) {1}", match.Groups["one"].Value, match.Groups["two"].Value);
               else
                   output = string.Format("({0}) {1}-{2}", match.Groups["one"].Value, match.Groups["two"].Value, match.Groups["three"].Value);
           }
```